# Adding SUM function SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add these minutes from different columns together but when I try and run this statement I see nothing but blanks. I have tried multiple things, I think its in there where clause. I will be adding in 4 more columns once this is working !

```
SELECT [School Name],
   SUM(mins1)
   ,SUM(mins2) as mins2
  ,SUM(mins3) as mins3
   ,SUM(mins4) as mins4
   ,SUM(mins1+mins2+mins3+mins4) as Minutes
 FROM [dbo].[George].[TEST_TEMP_TABLE]
 WHERE serv1 IS NOT NULL 
AND serv1 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND serv2 IS NOT NULL 
AND serv2 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND serv3 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND serv3 IS NOT NULL 
AND serv4 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND serv4 IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [School Name]
ORDER BY [School Name]
 GO
```

Comment: Do `select * from test_temp_table where serv1 = 'Speech...' and serv2 = 'Speech..' and serv3 = 'Speech...' and serv4 = 'Speech...'` and see if min1, min2, min3 and min4 columns have data.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do here. Do you realize that checking for a given string AND that it is also NOT NULL is redundant. There are no string values that can be NULL and 'Speech Language Therapy' at the same time. I have a feeling you want to use OR instead of AND but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the conditions of your `WHERE` clause must be TRUE at the same time for each record, before the record is included in the sum.

Since you are seeing a blank output, it looks like you don't have any records where serv1, serv2, serv3 and serv4 are all NOT NULL at the same time.

Since it looks like you want to sum each of the mins-columns, only when the respective serv-column contains "Speech Language Therapy", consider moving this condition to the `SELECT` part of your query, like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [School Name],
       SUM(CASE WHEN serv1 = 'Speech Language Therapy' THEN mins1 ELSE 0 END) as mins1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN serv2 = 'Speech Language Therapy' THEN mins2 ELSE 0 END) as mins2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN serv3 = 'Speech Language Therapy' THEN mins3 ELSE 0 END) as mins3
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN serv4 = 'Speech Language Therapy' THEN mins4 ELSE 0 END) as mins4
    FROM [dbo].[George].[TEST_TEMP_TABLE]
    GROUP BY [School Name]
)
SELECT [School Name]
    , mins1, mins2, mins3, mins4
    , mins1 + mins2 + mins3 + mins4 as Minutes
FROM cte
ORDER BY [School Name]
```

Here, I have moved the calculation of mins1..mins4 into a CTE, in order to make it easier to calculate the sum of all 4 outside the CTE (to avoid having to repeat each CASE-statement again).

Also note that it is unnecessary to check for `serv1 IS NOT NULL` when you already have a condition for `serv1 = 'Speech Language Therapy'`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to re-write your SQL to be somewhat like this:

```
SELECT [School Name],
   SUM(coalesce(mins1,0)) as mins1total,
   SUM(coalesce(mins2,0)) as mins2total,
   SUM(coalesce(mins3,0)) as mins3total,
   SUM(coalesce(mins4,0)) as mins4total,
   SUM(coalesce(min1,0) + coalesce(min2,0) + coalesce(min3,0) + coalesce(min4,0)) as alltotal
 FROM [dbo].[George].[TEST_TEMP_TABLE]
 WHERE 
   serv1 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
   AND serv2 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
   AND serv3 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
   AND serv4 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
GROUP BY [School Name]
ORDER BY [School Name]
```